# Dynamically changing layout in application

Tags: java, android

I want my users to have the ability to choose a few buttons which would be transferred to a different page, like a "favourite buttons" page. To do this, I need to change the layout from the app. I would like the modified layout to persist even after closing the app. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: SO yo want want a user to select things which would generate buttons on a screen in the order a user picks the buttons right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For This you should make some activity with different layout.
If you don't want to add more activity just use this:

```
private void SwitchLayout2() 
{
    RelativeLayout Layout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    RelativeLayout Layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);

    // Enable Layout 2 and Disable Layout 1
    Layout1 .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void SwitchLayout1() 
{
    RelativeLayout Layout1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    RelativeLayout Layout2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);

    // Enable Layout 1 & Disable Layout2
    Layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: the problem is there will be 100 buttons end they may choose any of them and in any order. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: The question is about generating a new layout on the fly, not displaying a different layout.

Comment: Ethan, maybe ou know how to do this?